# Поиск значений (например, NaN) в таблице по всем колонкам сразу

Tags: sql, postgresql

Коллеги, я видел похожие вопросы, но, думаю, вдруг что-то изменилось за те годы, которые прошли с тех пор, как они были заданы.

Есть таблица(-ы) со многими полями. Таблица может быть одна или их может быть много и мы можем их объединить по какому-то уникальному полю. Изначально задача была получить записи не содержащие `NaN` ни в одном из полей, но, на самом деле, вопрос шире - вместо `NaN` может быть любое значение.

То есть, если я ищу по одному полю, то, очевидно:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE field_name != 'NaN'::NUMERIC;
```

Если я ищу по всем полям, то мне надо так или иначе явно указывать названия полей и таблиц. А вот нет чего-то такого:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE table_name.* != 'NaN'::NUMERIC;
```

*(Я знаю - это не работает)*

То есть, либо перечислять названия полей вручную, либо с помощью скрипта получать названия и генерировать динамически, либо какие-то очень витиеватые (на мой взгляд) динамические запросы. Во всех этих случаях мне проще затащить все таблицы в `pandas` и легко и приятно избавится от `NaN`. Но вдруг можно легко и приятно, но через SQL?

Спасибо!

Comment: И что будете делать с этими полями(строками, таблицами)? Что в SQL, что в Pandas.

Comment: @ValNik ML буду делать. Но вопрос носит и прикладной и исследовательский характер.

Comment: ML - это высоко. С таблицами что будете делать? Чистить NaN (удалять стоки), заменять чем-нибудь (чем?).

Comment: @ValNik мне казалось из вопроса должно быть понятно. « Изначально задача была получить записи не содержащие NaN ни в одном из полей». То есть, либо я на стороне базы получаю только те записи, которые не содержат NaN, либо на стороне клиента (допустим это скрипт на питоне+пандас) удаляю строки с NaN.

Comment: Я привел пример решения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример:

```
create table test (val1 int,val2 int);
insert  into test values
 (1,2)
,(3,null)
,(null,4)
,(null,null)
;
```

Запрос

```
select *
    -- строки содержащие только null
  ,case when t.* is null then 1 else 0 end fIsNull
    -- строки не содержащие null
  ,case when t.* is not null then 1 else 0 end fIsNotNull
    -- строки содержащие не null значения
  ,case when not (t.* is null) then 1 else 0 end fIsNotIsNull
    -- строки содержащие null значения
  ,case when not (t.* is not null) then 1 else 0 end fIsNotIsNotNull
from test t
```

Результат

| val1 | val2 | fIsNull | fIsNotNull | fIsNotIsNull | fIsNotIsNotNull |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | null | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| null | 4 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| null | null | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Для любопытства, с такими данными

```
insert  into test values
 (1,2)
,(3,null)
,(null,4)
,(null,null)
,('NaN'::numeric,null)
,('NaN'::numeric,2)
;
```

запрос

```
select *
  ,concat(t.*) ts
from test t
-- where strpos(concat(t.*),'NaN')=0
```

выдаст результат

| val1 | val2 | ts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | (1,2) |
| 3 | null | (3,) |
| null | 4 | (,4) |
| null | null | (,) |
| NaN | null | (NaN,) |
| NaN | 2 | (NaN,2) |

```
select *
from test t
where  t.* is not null and  strpos(concat(t.*),'NaN')=0
```

| val1 | val2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |

Comment: Про null мне понятно, спасибо. Непонятно про NaN.

Comment: NaN - понятие на клиентской стороне. Если в базе null - у клиента Null или NaN - смотря что за клиент.   Перейдет-ли "not number" в базе в "NaN" - вопрос к клиенту (фронтенду). NaN у клиента перейдет в 0 или Null базе - это  к нему же вопрос. Вообщем, в базе NaN нет:)

Comment: Значит, у меня какая-то волшебная база, раз там NaN есть. У меня в вопросе первый пример кода возвращает строки не содержащие NaN. Причем именно NaN. Не ноль, не null.

Comment: значит волшебная, да.

Comment: Всем неверующим (и я тоже был не в курсе!) раздел 8.1.6 документации PostgreSQL : В дополнение к обычным числовым значениям тип numeric принимает следующие специальные
значения:
Infinity
-Infinity
NaN

Comment: @AlexeyTrukhanov, посмотри тут, может пойдет: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25858859/how-to-check-if-number-is-nan

Comment: @Ingvar спасибо, я читал это. Тут как раз описывается, как искать NaN в таблице, я этим воспользовался.  Но вопрос-то не просто в поиске NaN, а в поиске сразу по всей строке.

Comment: @AlexeyTrukhanov, еще варик: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/236674/how-to-search-for-a-string-in-all-columns-of-a-table

Comment: @Ingvar да, спасибо, тоже видел, но тут тоже, видите, надо перечислять поля. То есть, надо их запросить и как-то генерировать, либо на уровне базы, либо на уровне клиента. А хотелось чтобы просто :) Но, судя по всему, не выйдет. Более или менее реальный вариант, это переписать все NaN в базе на null, тогда можно фильтровать так, как в этом ответе.

Comment: У Вас в таблице, наверно, не только числовые поля. Также есть Ид, Дата и прочее. Поэтому перечислять придется.

Comment: @ValNik нет, таблицы, о которых я говорю содержат только нумерики, в этом не будет проблемы. Вся служебная нечисловая информация в отдельной таблице.

Comment: Добавил в мой ответ пример. Возможно, подойдет.

Comment: @AlexeyTrukhanov, мой крайний коммент: пообщался с разработчиками PostgreSQL Pro - ответ никак. Самый лучший вариант - динамически сформировать запрос в функции по "материалам" служебных таблиц. Успехов.

Comment: @Ingvar В любом случае, благодарю за потраченное время и за желание помочь! Удачи!

Comment: @ValNik Это работает! Спасибо!

Comment: И Вам спасибо за вопрос. Узнал новое для себя.

Comment: @AlexeyTrukhanov, конструкция case when t.* is null then 1 else 0 end fIsNull вполне возможно меняется на более короткую coalesce(t.*,0), но нужно проверить!

Comment: @Ingvar на сколько я понимаю, ValNik привел конструкцию с case/then/else только для иллюстрации, на самом деле, для моей задачи достаточно всего лишь where t.* is not null.